# Como agrupar 2 circulos centrados

Tags: angular, ionic

Tengo un problema estoy intentado mostrar 2 div sobrepuestos para simular una cuenta atrás animada...ya tengo lo siguiente pero no consigo centrarlos y que se vea igual o similar para distintas resoluciones..... ¿Podrían ayudarme a centrar los div?

```
    <div id="container">
        <div class="contorno"></div>
        <div class="circulo">{{ countDown }}</div>
    </div>
```

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.contorno {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;

  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: -webkit-center;
  background-color: transparentize($color: #fff, $amount: 0.9);
  animation: myAnim 1s ease 0s infinite normal forwards;
}
@keyframes myAnim {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }

  50% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
}
.circulo {
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #c95151;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

a lo que he llegado...

[image: ver]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma que tienes para centrarlos es usar `display:grid` en el contenedor con `place-items: center` y luego asignar ambos hijos al mismo `grid-area`.

Quedaría algo así:

```
#container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.contorno {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 10px;

  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: transparentize($color: #fff, $amount: 0.9);
  animation: myAnim 1s ease 0s infinite normal forwards;
}
@keyframes myAnim {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }

  50% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
}
.circulo {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  z-index:2;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #c95151;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

saludos